# Combining 3 boolean masks in Python

Tags: python, boolean-logic

I have 3 lists:

```
a = [True, False, True]
b = [False, False, True]
c = [True, True, False]
```

When I type

```
a or b or c
```

I want to get back a list that's

```
[True, True, True]
```

but I'm getting back

```
[True, False, True]
```

Any ideas on why? And how can I combine these masks?

Comment: a is true... and thats what you get.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your `or` operators are comparing the lists as entire objects, not their elements. Since `a` is not an empty list, it evaluates as true, and becomes the result of the `or`. `b` and `c` are not even evaluated.

To produce the logical OR of the three lists position-wise, you have to iterate over their contents and OR the values at each position. To convert a bunch of iterables into a list of their grouped elements, use `zip()`. To check if any element in an iterable is true (the OR of its entire contents), use `any()`. Do these two at once with a list comprehension:

```
mask = [any(tup) for tup in zip(a, b, c)]
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks! In case anyone is wondering, to check if all elements are True, use all() instead of any().

Answer (score 13):

How about this:

```
from numpy import asarray as ar

a = [True, False, True]
b = [False, False, True]
c = [True, True, False]
```

Try:

```
>>> ar(a) | ar(b) | ar(c)                  #note also the use `|` instead of `or`
array([ True, True, True], dtype=bool)
```

So no need for `zip` etc.

Comment: You need to convert back from `array` to `list` at the end there, but definitely a nice idea!

Comment: Good alternative solution for those who are already using numpy data structures. It's probably not worth the conversion from list->array->list (plus the overhead of loading the numpy module) just for this.

Answer (score 7):

`or` returns the first operand if it evaluates as true, and a non-empty list evaluates as `true`; so, `a or b or c` will always return `a` if it's a non-empty list.

Probably you want

```
[any(t) for t in zip(a, b, c)]
```

(this works also for element-wise `and` if you replace `any` with `all`)

Answer (score 3):

`a` is treated as true because it contains values; `b`, `c` is not evaluated.

```
>>> bool([])
False
>>> bool([True])
True
>>> bool([False])
True

>>> [False] or [True]
[False]
```

According to [Boolean Operations](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations):

> The expression `x or y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is true, its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
a = [True, False, True]
b = [False, False, True]
c = [True, True, False]

res = [a[i] or b[i] or c[i] for i in range(len(a))]
print res
```

Comment: Iterate directly rather than by index: `[any(tup) for tup in zip(a, b, c)]`

Comment: Rather than iterating by index (not pythonic), use either zip(a,b,c) or map(None,a,b,c) (if a,b,c are different sizes).

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to do it fast (large arrays) using numpy:

```
import numpy as np
a = [True, False, True,...]
b = [False, False, True,...]
c = [True, True, False,...]
res = (np.column_stack((a,b,c)).any(axis=1)
print res
```

Note that `a` becomes the first column, `b` the second, and so on when using `np.column_stack()`. Then do a `np.any()` (logical OR) on that `array` along `axis=1` which will compare the first elements of `a`,`b`, and `c`, and so on, and so on; resulting in a boolean vector that is the same length as the vectors you want to compare.

Answer (score 2):

how about

```
result = numpy.logical_or(a, b, c)
print(result)
```

Comment: numpy.logical_or only takes 2 arrays as input,

Answer (score 1):

This is a good place to use one of python's [asterisk functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters) (`*args`, `**kwargs`), which will allow you to pass 3 or 300000 lists.

```
    a = [True, False, True]
    b = [False, False, True]
    c = [True, True, False]
    data_lists = [a,b,c]
```

Here you use `*` to expand that list as arguments, `zip` to rearrange your data into columns (as lists), and `any` to check if any cell in that column is `True`.

```
    [any(l) for l in zip(*data_lists)]
    [True, True, True]
```

If you're working with a lot of lists it's the same, e.g.

```
    import numpy as np
    data_lists =  [[True if (i == j) else False for i in range(7)] for j in range(7)]
    np.matrix(data_lists)
    matrix([[ True, False, False, False, False, False, False],
            [False,  True, False, False, False, False, False],
            [False, False,  True, False, False, False, False],
            [False, False, False,  True, False, False, False],
            [False, False, False, False,  True, False, False],
            [False, False, False, False, False,  True, False],
            [False, False, False, False, False, False,  True]])
    [any(l) for l in zip(*data_lists)]
    [True, True, True, True, True, True, True]
```